# Test Azure APIM Oauth 2.0 with Postman to generate jwt

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, postman, azure-api-management

I have configured an OAuth 2.0 server for my Azure API Management. I have tested it using Developer Portal (Legacy) to generate Auth Code and it worked fine. However, I want to implement it for a machine to machine scenario and need to test it with Postman to generate a jwt from an endpoint. I'm not sure how I can do this. Need Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to implement the Client Credentials flow for the server to server OAUTH Authorization flow. Following blog provides you with the step by step process to set up the Client Credentials flow.
["OAuth 2.0 Authorization with the Client Credentials Flow on Azure API Management"](https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/oauth2-client-credentials-flow-on-azure-api-management)

I follow another practice on top of the steps mentioned in above blog post. I create a token endpoint specifically to get the access token and I implement the logic to call the AAD token endpoint in this API rather than giving the azure AAD url to external customers

Update: Authorization code grant flow can not be tested using the API testing tool as the flow requires explicit human intervention to authorize the app to grant access to the resources.

Comment: Thank you. I went through the link you shared and it works fine when grant-type is client credentials. However, I am checking on how to get token with grant-type set as Authorization Code only. The second option which you sounds good. Is there some refernce to how you configured it?

Comment: Hi, apologies if my response created confusion, When I said authorization code, I was actually talking about the access token. I have edited my response now. And just to clarify , the authorization grant code flow can not be tested using postman, the flow itself by definition requires human intervention

Comment: Yes, understood Mandar. I would like to work out something similar to what you have mentioned about the practice which you follow. Is there some blog of yours regarding this or some reference link which I can follow? Thank you.